# Won't able to connect to sql server 2008 in android using JDBC

Tags: android, jdbc

I use sqljdbc4.jar and yet i got error like "java.sql.SQLException:No suitable driver".
Can any one help me out from it?

Answer (score 0):

That exception usually means that your connection URL syntax is incorrect.  Post it so we can see.

Comment: String driverName = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
     String URL = "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://CCOIT:1433;DatabaseName=TT";

Comment: String username = "sa";
String password = "narendra";   Class.forName(driverName);
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,username,password);

Answer (score 0):

You can't access sqlserver in Android .It only support Sqlite.If you want to access sql server then better to use webservice.